# Firebase android hashmap integer value turned into Long

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
 changeweek = (Map<String,ArrayList<Integer>>)dataSnapshot.child("week").getValue();
                    ArrayList<Integer> test = changeweek.get("Monday");
                    Log.d("changeweek",changeweek.toString());
                    int j = test.get(2);
```

I get an error in the last line which is the following:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
>                                                                                 at com.example.fake9.tendee.ScheduleActivity$1$1.onDataChange(ScheduleActivity.java:107)

I don't know how this happens since I am storing Arraylist of integers into the hashmap. The following is a picture of the database.

[image]

Comment: Firebase does not want to assume the maximum value of your data, so it may err on the conversative side (using longs instead of ints). Can you just use an ArrayList<Long> instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase SDK internally stores all integer-like number values as Long values, whether or not you want.  This helps defend against possibly very large numbers as values.

Your cast to a Map with values of type Integer is overriding that, then causing problems at runtime when the types don't match.  You can correct this by simply changing your value type from Integer to Long.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than directly converting **long to int**, convert long to ***string*** using ***String.valueOf()*** then we can easily convert ***string*** value to **int** using **Integer.parseInt()**

So you can go with this,

**

> int j = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(test.get(2)));

**